# My Discord Bot Returns "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am building a simple discord bot on Python to put space between each character of the input and some other things.

My code is here:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

def bos(a):
    a=a.upper()
    a=a.replace("0", "SIFIR")
    a=a.replace("1", "BİR")
    a=a.replace("2", "İKİ")
    a=a.replace("3", "ÜÇ")
    a=a.replace("4", "DÖRT")
    a=a.replace("5", "BEŞ")
    a=a.replace("6", "ALTI")
    a=a.replace("7", "YEDİ")
    a=a.replace("8", "SEKİZ")
    a=a.replace("9", "DOKUZ")
    a=" ".join(a)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('*'):
        a = message.content[1:]
        await client.send_message(message.channel, a.bos(a))
        #counter = 0
        #tmp = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Calculating messages...')
        #async for log in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=100):
        #    if log.author == message.author:
        #        counter += 1

        #await client.edit_message(tmp, 'You have {} messages.'.format(counter))
    #elif message.content.startswith('!sleep'):
        #await asyncio.sleep(5)
        #await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Done sleeping')

client.run('token')
```

But when I write `*test` on discord, terminal returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot2.py", line 32, in on_message
    await client.send_message(message.channel, a.bos(a))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bos'
```

Can someone help me fix this code?

Comment: What is `a.bos(a)` meant to do?

Comment: It's telling you `a` is a string. Strings don't have your function `bos` as an attribute. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with `a.bos(a)`

Comment: I tried to call the function, I declared beforehand. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bos` is a regular function, not a `str` method. Further, assigning to `a` inside the function won't affect the argument outside the call; you need to return a new string.

```
def bos(a):
    return " ".join(a.upper().
                      replace("0", "SIFIR").
                      replace("1", "BİR").
                      replace("2", "İKİ").
                      replace("3", "ÜÇ").
                      replace("4", "DÖRT").
                      replace("5", "BEŞ").
                      replace("6", "ALTI").
                      replace("7", "YEDİ").
                      replace("8", "SEKİZ").
                      replace("9", "DOKUZ"))


...
await client.send_message(message.channel, bos(a))
#                                          ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. It helped me very much.

Answer (score 0):

`bos` is not a method on `str`; it's a globally scoped function. Instead of `a.bos(a)`, simply use `bos(a)`.